# Global event handler on click outside prevents firing react events

Tags: reactjs, dom-events, react-dom

I have implemented the click-outside hook to close my menu component on `mousedown` on the document:

```
const useClickOutside = onClickOutside => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  useEffect(
    () => {
      const handleClickOutside = e => {
        if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
          onClickOutside(e);
        }
      };
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
      };
    },
    [onClickOutside, ref]
  );
  return ref;
};
```

The menu has an input which attaches an `onBlur` event handler:

```
const Input = ({ onValueEnter }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const handleValueChange = e => setValue(e.target.value);
  const handleBlur = () => onValueEnter(value);

  return (
   <input onBlur={handleBlur} value={value} onChange={handleValueChange} />
  );
};

const Menu = ({ onClose }) => {
  const ref = useClickOutside(onClose);
  return (
    <div ref={ref} className="menu">
      <h1>Enter value</h1>
      <Input onValueEnter={handleValueEnter} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

The problem is that the `onBlur` event on the input never fires if I have focus inside the input and click outside the menu. [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ll12kv44wm) example is here.

Apparently since `react` has implemented its own event delegation system by attaching events to the top level instead of the actual dom nodes, global event handlers (like those registered with `document.addEventListener`) run before the react event handlers ([github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7094)).

So my question is, how to work around this problem? Is it even possible to somehow make the `onBlur` event handler run first and then run the global event handler?

EDIT: I am already using a hack with `setTimeout` inside the   `onClose` to temporarily make it work but I would really like to avoid it and find a better solution instead.

Answer (score 0):

I hacked something together to make it work. It revolves around using forwardRef and imperativeHandle to access the value from child when closing. I don't know if that solves your question though.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/zw7jjopqq4

Comment: Thank you for the idea! But I am already using a hack with setTimeout to defer the execution of the onClose callback, so I would really like to know whether there is a better way of doing this, and why this happens in the first place. Moreover the input itself is inside a library so I don’t have much acces to it. I will edit my question to include those details.