# Is there a way to create a global click handler that is guaranteed to run after other click handlers in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dom-events

I have a ReactJS based application written in TypeScript for which we implemented certain click handlers.

Other teams contribute to this and application and can even implement their own handlers and events. The thing is we need to make sure one specific click handler needs to be guaranteed to run after other click handlers in the application.

This needs to be global (outside React) click handler.

I know I can manage global DOM events in React, even using hooks but I haven't found a way to follow and respect a defined hierarchy for click events or any type of event whatsoever.

I've also reviewed this Stack Overflow question [global events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55347839/global-event-handler-on-click-outside-prevents-firing-react-events) but can't find a way to make sure my click handler takes priority over others at the same level or guarantee mine to appear in DOM before others.

I'd appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: What you mean by "guaranteed to run after other click handlers"? Do you need to wait until all not global handler do their job, and call "global" handler only after them? What about async handlers?

Comment: Thanks @AndreyProgr that's exactly what I mean my click handler should be executed at last after all other click handlers. As for async handlers I didn't see any means to make sure other handlers finish before mine.

Comment: One way would be to create your own event dispatch queue mechanism and register all your handlers to it instead of native DOM nodes directly. By using that kind of proxy, you could control and guarantee the dispatch order.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap default click handler with your own function. The easiest way to do this is to put this code to your custom clickable component. For example:

```
  const Button = ({ onClick, ...props }) => {
    const handleClick = (...args) => {
      // you should add try ... catch and/or await here if needed
      onClick && onClick(...args);
      // this is your custom "global" handler imported from somewhere
      handleGlobalButtonClick();
    }
    return <button onClick={handleClick} {...props}> click me! </button>;
  }
```

This is the solution I would suggest you to use. Attempt to "globally" inject such a function to all clickable components by manipulating global objects will make your codebase highly coupled and significantly reduce maintaibanility.

Also you can do, basically, the same by creating [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html). In this case you will get more flexibility. But what way to choose highly depends on the architecture of your project.

Comment: nothing would stop some other code from doing this either, possibly after you've wrapped it.  So there's no guarantee this makes you "last"

Comment: Yep, you can add several hundrends wrappers, but the first one defined here will be the last one in the call stack? So, what is wrong with this code?